# Block incoming calls

Tags: android, phone-call, callblocking

my VoiP-client would like to block all incoming calls to the phone while my own call is taking place. Is it possible to do this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with the current SDK no, You can monitor incoming calls and give the user the option to answer with your application instead of the native app

Comment: How is the user offered to choose app to answer with, trough an intentchooser? Thanks for you help.

Comment: Yep you can register to listen for that intent and start your application on that intent

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can block incoming calls. Using this code

```
 String phonestate = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

 try 
    {
        if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equalsIgnoreCase(phonestate)) 
        {
            try 
            {
                TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
                Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                m.setAccessible(true);
                telephonyService = (com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (prefStatus != null) 
            {
                if (count == 1) 
                {
                    telephonyService.endCall();
                    String prefLoginemail = myloginpref.getString("emailid", null);
                    System.out.println(printdata + " prefLoginemail :: "+ prefLoginemail);

                    Global.mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mxcontext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notifyDetails = new Notification(com.CellPhoneTerror.R.drawable.icon1,"CellPhoneTerror!", System.currentTimeMillis());
                    myIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mxcontext, 0, new Intent(mxcontext, clsHomePage.class), 0);

                    notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(mxcontext,"You Got a Call from Blocked Number.", "",myIntent);
                    notifyDetails.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                    Global.mNotificationManager.notify(Global.SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID,notifyDetails);

                }
            }
        }
        if (prefIncomingBlock.equals("true")) 
        {
            if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equalsIgnoreCase(phonestate)) 
            {
                if (count == 0) 
                {
                    System.out.println("if Cellphoneterror:"+ Global.clsIncomingNum);
                    Intent block = new Intent(context, dialogbox1.class);
                    block.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(block);
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: -1 I think it is pretty that the asker wanted to know how to do this.

Comment: Sorry friends, But my network was down so I was not able to put example here. Anyway Thanks for comment.

Comment: How can you avoid the delay and sometimes one or two rings before its blocked?