# Don't be disturbed by call or message during 5 minutes : Android

Tags: android, phone-call, forwarding

I made a sort of mp3 player but I wanted to add a functionality. I don't want to be disturbed by a call or a message while the music is playing. I already thought about 3 options, but they all have issues:

- Enable and disable airplane mode: My first idea, but when I switch to airplane mode and switch back to normal, the phone will ask me to enter my pin code... That's not an option for me.
- Enable silent mode: that was a good idea but when I get a call, even if the phone is in silent mode, the music is stopped...
- Enable call forwarding: I couldn't find a simple way to do that...

**So here are my questions:**

Can I enable call forwarding easily (programmatically)?
Do you see another way to be peaceful when I'm playing an mp3?

Comment: It might help you: [this answer use a BroadcastReceiver](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9904826/2668136), [this one prevents the incoming message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378431/how-to-block-an-incoming-message-in-android) and [this is to prevent incoming calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334465/block-incoming-calls/6841757#6841757). I hope this will be useful, good luck.